# HTML form autofill with Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, url, variables, autofill

i am developing a web tracker for my site, and one of the ways i am transferring data, is by auto-filling form data on page load, with javascript queries being used to fill each field.....

i just need strings of text to be transferred from the form to another php script.....

this side of it is easy.....

the form ( and data collected on page load ) is hidden in an invisible iframe, so that it can do its work in the background....

i need the url of the main page (not the iframe) to be auto inserted into one of the form fields.....

heres what i have so far,,,,

this is the code that is displayed on parent page (in this example "events"):

```
    <iframe src="/track/track.html?events" height="500" width="500" scrolling="no" border="0"></iframe>
```

i know i said invisible iframe, the 500x500 size is so i can see behind the scenes while developing....

then in the iframe the code i have is :

```
    <?php 
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

    $my_t = getdate(date("U"));

    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    ?>


    <html>

    <body> 

    <form action="/track/location.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="time" value="<?php echo "$my_t[weekday], $my_t[month] $my_t[mday], $my_t[year] - $my_t[hours]:$my_t[minutes]:$my_t[seconds]" ?>">

    <input type="text" name="ip" value="<?php echo $ip ?>">



    // script A //

    <script type="text/javascript">

    document.write(window.location.search);

    </script>

    // end script A //


    // script B //

    <script>

    var url = ['alert(window.location.search)'];
    document.write("<input type=\"text\" name=\"url\" value=\"" + url + "\">");

    </script>

    // end script B //



    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

    </form>
```

script A will produce a statement of text "?events" where inserted as "document.write"

script B will produce a text box with the text "alert(window.location.search)" pre inserted as a value.... which is kind of what i want.....

i basically need to be able to combine script a and b so that it will write the (window.location.search) data ("?events") in the text box instead of the plain text java command....

i will be very greatful if anyone can help me, thanks in advance guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
var url = ['alert(' + window.location.search + ')'];
```

Comment: i had to modify it to 

        var url = ['' + window.location.search + ''];

as it was displaying "alert(?events)" in the txt box,

Comment: however since i changed it, the code is doing exactly what i want so thanks so much for your help

Comment: the '' inside the square brackets is 2x single quotes, it just looks like double quotes

Comment: @DJ-P.I.M.P Since window.location.search is already a string and you don't want the alert part you do not need to put the quotes. You should be able to simply use var url = [window.location.search]. And why do you need the brackets?

Comment: that was a noob error.... i have recently written some complex php scripting, and i am doing the same now, but the only way i can get the url transfereed over to the iframe is client side, once the page has loaded....

Comment: and i have never edited javascript before, only basic stuff like variables in pre programmed scripts..... but now im writing my own i might have a few coding errors, as i am used to the simplicity of php :)

Comment: i tried just using var url = [window.location.search] but it displayed the actual text inside the square brackets, it didnt process is and insert the url like i wanted

Comment: but i have got as far as catching the info in next script and now am getting to work on processing it into a line by line text file lol

Comment: ok done that, now i have a log file that collects the date/time, visitors ip, visitors city, and page viewed..... now i need to write a big ass script to interpret the text file data